# Unable to edit modules on home page after localizing

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

After localizing the website to support both English and French, I added a container to the theme. I was able to successfully add and edit a HTML module into this container, however when we went to edit any of the modules settings on the page afterwards, we encountered this error:

```
Error: is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Modules.ModuleSettingsPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Error: is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.PermissionProvider.CanDeleteModule(ModuleInfo module) at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Modules.ModuleSettingsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

All other pages are unaffected. The only thing custom on this page would be the skin. There are custom modules created and installed, however they are not on the affected page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information about your issue, but is seems as your custom theme(skin) has something wrong. Switch the page theme to a well known one that is working (the standard Xcillion is a good choice), and make sure you switch both the page skin and container, and also containers for all modules on the page. As soon as you get rid of the error, compare your custom theme with the one working allright. Or maybe you can custom your theme based on a correct one.